# Адаптивное youtube video в картинке.

Tags: html5, css3, iframe

Всем привет! Был бы очень благодарен за совет касательно верстки: 
На странице есть блок с заданным бэкргаунд фоном в виде картинки ноутбука. Вопрос мой заключается в том что надо поместить во внутрь изображения видео с ютуба. Чисто теоретически, мне это удалось, но блок с видео не адаптивный и на маленьких разрешениях съезжает. Буду рад услышать как можно сделать видео адаптивным. Прилагаю код и скрины. [image: Как должно видео смотреться][image: Вот здесь видео съезжает]

```css
.videoWrapper 
 position: relative
 padding-bottom: 56%
 height: 0

.videoWrapper iframe
 position: absolute
 top: 38px
 left: 138px
 width: 71%
 height: 82%

.video-block
 width: 100%
 max-width: 1000px
 margin: 0 auto
 min-height: 616px
 background: url('../images/laptop_1.png') no-repeat
 background-size: contain
```

```html
  



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: left: 138px отсюда отступ идет думаю.. медиазапросы добавь

Comment: @Volodymyr здравствуйте, вы предлагаете на медиа запросах менять left для выравнивания?

Comment: на мелких экранах да..отступ нужно менять.. ну или в % отступ сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какие могут быть пиксели при адаптивной верстке? В общем, все не так. Вот код:

```
<body>

<div id="video">
    <div class="video-container">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WlnexV2eAvI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    body {
        background: #c2c2c2;
    }
    #video {
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
        background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/4.jpg) no-repeat top center;
        background-size: contain;
    }
    .video-container {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .video-container iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 7.3%;
        left: 17%;
        margin: auto;
        width: 64.8%;
        height: 64.8%;
    }
</style>

</body>
```

Вот [работающий пример](http://test.kagg.eu/so/623770.html).